# foreign key table datafield not found while assigning to gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to assign foreign key table datafields to gridview. It is throwing below error.

> A field or property with the name 'Dim_Hierarchy.Business_Unit_Name'
>   was not found on the selected data source.

### Code Behind

```
  Public Function GetInitiativeDataList(ByVal client_Idx As Integer) As List(Of Fact_Initiative)
    Dim fact_Initiative As IList(Of Fact_Initiative)
    Dim SGAEntities As New SGATLEntities()

    fact_Initiative = (From factInitiative In SGAEntities.Fact_Initiative Where factInitiative.Client_Idx = client_Idx).ToList()

    Return fact_Initiative
End Function
```

### ASPX Page

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvInitiavtives" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="Grid" 
      RowStyle-Width="30px" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader"   RowStyle-CssClass="GridItem" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="GridAltItem">
      <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Dim_Hierarchy.Business_Unit_Name" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="NotSet" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Dim_Hierarchy.Business_Unit_Function" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="NotSet" />
                ......
                ......
```

[image]

Am I doing in correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Since you like using `Entity Framework`. `Aspx` has an `EntityDatasource` and for hooking up a related table there is the `Include` attribute for each navigation property that the model builds. [Entity Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef). Then your Binding looks like:

```
 asp:TemplateField...
  asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("tablename.fieldname") %>...
```